# Getting full property name using ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an HtmlHelper that will create Bootstrap-compatible form fields. My first goal was to create an HtmlHelper that will create the surrounding div:

```
<div class="control-group"> ... </div>
```

Following the excellent advice here and also here I managed to get it to work relatively quickly. But it doesn't always work.

I have a ViewModel with a complex property, so in my form I access the field `m=>m.Complex.Element` . In my helper I check the element for validation errors. I use `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData)` . The metadata I get back has the property name `Element`, and not `Complex.Element`.

When I check the ModelState for this property, I can't find it, because the ModelState keeps the full name - `Complex.Element`.

I can look for partial matches, hoping there's no other Element, but that seems like a nasty bug waiting to happen. How can I get the full property name from the expression?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a good thing the MVC sources are out in the open. The proper way to get the ModelState property name is by using

```
var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

Answer (score 7):

I've used the following to get it for the current model before, you may have to append the property name to this to get it for the property though.

```
ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
```

Otherwise pull out reflector/ilspy/whatever and check what your EditorFor/TextBoxFor or whatever method is rendering your editor does.

Comment: I get an empty prefix. I'll look into the MVC 3 sources and see how Microsoft solves this. I hoped someone else knew it and could save me the time.

Comment: I use this (without "ViewContext.") within my HtmlHelper-Extensions and my Editor/Display-Templates. Works fine so far

Comment: when writing your own html helper extension you can get it from there `htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`

Answer (score 4):

I've used a combination of both answers for an attribute I needed.  Together, both of these answers provide a working attribute I can use in both views and nested editor templates.  Here's my example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HasErrorClassFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    string expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    string htmlFieldPrefix = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;

    string fullyQualifiedName;

    if (htmlFieldPrefix.Length > 0)
    {
        fullyQualifiedName = string.Join(".", htmlFieldPrefix, expressionText);
    }
    else
    {
        fullyQualifiedName = expressionText;
    }

    bool isValid = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(fullyQualifiedName);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("has-error");
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```